# Is the area of the graph equal to the amount of rainwater?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, functions, graphing-functions

The function $f$ gives the instantaneous rate of change in the amount of rainwater in a given
Vessel as a function of time $t$ over the course of $60$ minutes.

The graph of $f$ is :

[image]

At time $t = 0$ there are $R_0$ $cm^3$ rainwater in this vessel.

(a) Create a term to calculate the amount of rainwater (in $cm^3$) in this vessel for the time $t = 60$.

(b) Someone claims that at the time $t = 0$ there is at most $10 \ cm^3$ rainwater in the container. Use the graph to explain why this claim must be false.

$$$$

For (a) I have done the following :

Let $R(t)$ is the function that calculates the rainwater.

It holds that $f(t)=R'(t)$ and for $t_0$ there is $R_0$ in the vessel.

Then we have that \begin{align*}\int_0^{60}f(t)\, dt=\int_0^{60}R'(t)\, dt &\Rightarrow \int_0^{60}f(t)\, dt=R(60)-R(0) \\ & \Rightarrow \int_0^{60}f(t)\, dt=R(60)-R_0\\  &  \Rightarrow R(60)=\int_0^{60}f(t)\, dt+R_0 \end{align*}
Is that correct?

As for (b) : The area of the graph of $f$ is the amount of rainwater, or not? But which part of the are do we have to use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer to question a) is correct.

On the other hand, the area of the graph is $0$, since the graph is $1$-dimensional. But the amount of rainwater at time $t=20$ is$$R_0+\int_0^{20}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=R_0-\int_0^{20}-f(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$And $\int_0^{20}-f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is greater than the area of the triangle whose vertices are $(0,0)$, $(20,0)$ and $(10,2)$. But the area of this triangle is $20~\textrm{cm}^3$. So, if the original amount was $\leqslant10~\textrm{cm}^3$, the amount when $t=20$ would be negative, which makes no sense.

Comment: So we suppose that $R_0$ is $10$. Then we have $$R(20)=R_0+\int_0^{20}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=R_0-\int_0^{20}-f(t)\,\mathrm dt=10-\int_0^{20}-f(t)\,\mathrm dt$$ Since $\int_0^{20}-f(t)\,\mathrm dt>20$ then $R(20)<10-20=-10$ which cannot be true. Have  I understood that correctly?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @RossMillikan I've edited my answer. Thank you.